# jquery mobile tabs as 2nd page

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I've got 2 pages

```
<div data-role="page" align="center" id="loginDivId">
</div>

<div data-role="tabs" id="tabs">
  <div data-role="navbar">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#tabs-1">Tab 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#tabs-2">Tab 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#tabs-3">Tab 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Essentially I display loginDivId to the user, they enter some data and when they hit a button I display the div with id=tabs

The problem is, I can swipe up on the login screen and see the tabs screen.  This is both before AND after logging in.

What I want is to have the login div display and the user to see no part of the tabs div.  Then I want to remove the login div altogether and only show the tabs div.

Does Jquery Mobile allow you to mix div's with different data-role (in my case page and tabs) in the same app?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have a button whose class is `okValid` :

```
<div data-role="page" align="center" id="loginDivId">
    <button type="button" class="okValid">Ok</button>
</div>

<div data-role="tabs" id="tabs" style="display:none;>
  <div data-role="navbar">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#tabs-1">Tab 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#tabs-2">Tab 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#tabs-3">Tab 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

And the js associated :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('okValid').click(function () {
    $('#loginDivId').fadeOut(250);
    $('#tabs').fadeIn(250);
  }); 
});
```